# Why this is not accessible in static methods such as static getDerivedStateFromProps(props,state) in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am a beginner in react and while learning lifecycle methods I came  to know getDerivedStateFromProps() is a method of mounting lifecycle but while going further I came to understand that this is not accessible to  static methods can anyone please explain why it is like this?

Answer (score 0):

This is not specific to React, but to JavaScript itself.

The [`static` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static) defines static methods or properties. The behavior you see is because neither static methods nor static properties can be called on instances of the class (and the `this` refers to the current instance of the class). Instead, `static` methods/properties are called on the class itself.

A demo may make it clearer:

```js
class MyClass {
  instanceProperty = 'instancePropertyValue';
  instanceMethod() {
    console.log('here, the `this` is accessible, as well as instance properties:');
    console.log(this.instanceProperty);
  }
  static staticProperty = 'staticPropertyValue';
  static staticMethod() {
    console.log('here, the `this` is NOT accessible, only static methods/properties:');
    console.log(MyClass.staticProperty);
  }
}

MyClass.staticMethod(); // works
// MyClass.instanceMethod(); // doesn't work

const myInstance = new MyClass();
myInstance.instanceMethod(); // works
// myInstance.staticMethod(); // doesn't work
```

Notice there's no React-specific code above.

Answer (score 0):

This is a core fundamental of Object Oriented Programming.
In React, every component when run creates an instance of a class. In object oriented programming, `static` properties exist on the [whole class](https://javascript.info/static-properties-methods) and not on the instance. (An instance of a class is called an object). `this` refers to the component instance, so every instance of the component will have a different `this`. Since in this case, there is no instance, there is no `this`.